# JPA @OneToMany join on part of a multipart key

Tags: java, database, jpa, join

A Profile table has a one to many association with a Privilege table. The privilege table has a multipart key, of a profile_id and a privilege_id. I want to join from the Profile table to the Privilege table only on the profile_id and get back a collection of privileges.

In my Profile class I have

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "PROF_ID")
public List<ProfilePrivilegeEO> getProfilePrivileges()
{
    return m_profilePrivileges;
}
```

My Privilege class has

```
private ProfilePrivilegeId m_profileId;

@EmbeddedId
public ProfilePrivilegeId getProfileId()
{
    return m_profileId;
}
```

Where ProfilePrivilegeId is

```
@Embeddable
public class ProfilePrivilegeId
    implements Serializable
{
    private Integer m_profileId;
    private Integer m_privNumber;

    @Column(name = "PROF_ID")
    public Integer getProfileId()
    {
        return m_profileId;
    }

    @Column(name = "PRIV_NUM")
    public Integer getPrivNumber()
    {
        return m_privNumber;
    }

    .....
}
```

However, when i do that the static weaver says:

```
The @JoinColumns on the annotated element [method getProfilePrivileges] from the entity     
class [class com.acme.ProfileEO] is incomplete. When the source entity class uses a 
composite primary key, a @JoinColumn must be specified for each join column using the 
@JoinColumns. Both the name and the referencedColumnName elements must be specified in 
each such @JoinColumn.
```

However, the Profile table has no knowledge of privilege_ids... I don't see why JPA should demand that i specify both keys of the privilege table, that's just an arbitrary decision made by jpa with no valid reason why... What do i need to do to get this to work? (I am using EclipseLInk.)

Answer (score 0):

Create an PrivilegeId class that encapsulate the ids. Make that class @Embedded and put it in the Privilege with @EmbeddedId.

In the PrivilegeId class, put an @OneToMany to the Profile and the privilege id.

Comment: The first part is what i did. The Profile is OneToMany to the Privilege. not the other way. The join is only on the profile_id.

Comment: What is ProfilePrivilegeEO?
Put the @JoinColumns annotation and use the two @JoinColumn there. This does not affect the generated schema negatively, because in the @OneToMany, the key is in the foreign class, the Privilege (exactly where it is actually and should be).

Comment: ProfilePrivilegeEO is the entity for the Privilege table. I don't have two @JoinColumns to specify from the Profile class, as it doesn't know about privileges. that is the problem.